# Promise Unexpected Behavior, Execution Order

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

Before Upgrading Chrome to 58, I had no errors.

**Further Explanation:** My code was working on sunday, I wasn't aware of the **async nature of execution**, found out about this two days later!

```
new Promise((s, f) => {
    console.log(1);
    s();
    console.log(2);
})
.then(r => {console.log(3)})

console.log(4);
```

OUTPUT:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 4
>
> 3

---

**1- Why does 'then' get executed after console.log(2) ???**

**Possible Answer:** because the promise result gets executed after the body returns

**2- Why does 'then' get executed after console.log(4) ???**

Comment: Promises aren't supposed to be synchronous. Imagine the resolver / rejector being `setTimeout(function () {...})` instead, and you'd get basically the same behavior.

Comment: i have this same order for all my test browsers (firefox/chrome/edge/opera). For the first question i don't know, but it seems logic that 3 comes after 4, like in a regular async call, the code following is executed before the callback.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts right, but my code was working on sunday, I wasn't aware of the async nature in execution, found out about this today, interesting!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value

Answer (score 1):

Because of the asynchronous nature of promises, the `then` handler will be stored in the event loop's message queue. Elements of this queue are processed whenever the JavaScript runtime's call stack is empty. In your scenario, `console.log(4);` needs to be run before the enclosing function can be taken off the call stack, at which point the JavaScript engine can start processing items from the message queue (assuming the enclosing function is the top-level function), resulting in running the code inside `then`.

Answer (score 0):

[Thank you @PatrickRoberts for providing a reference:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Promises are naturally ASYNC and get executed on the next event loop execution.